# Agg. with filter and groupby in Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing aggregation based on `groupBy` condition and applying some filter on my existing Spark/Scala DataFrame. But while executing my code I'm getting 'cannot resolve '`flag`' given input columns:'

```
val someDF = Seq(
 (1, 111,100,100,"C","5th","Y",11),
 (1, 111,100,100,"C","5th","Y",11),
 (2, 222,200,200,"C","5th","Y",22),
 (2, 222,200,200,"C","5th","Y",22)
 ).toDF("id","rollno","sub1","sub2","flag","class","status","sno")

var df2 = someDF.groupBy("id","rollno")
.agg(sum("sub1").alias("sub1"),sum("sub2").alias("sub2"))
.filter(col("flag") === "C")
.filter(length(col("rollno")) >= 2)
.filter(col("class") === ("5th") || col("class") === ("6th"))
.filter(substring(col("rollno"), 1, 2) === col("sno"))
.filter(col("status") === "Y")
.select("id", "rollno", "sub1", "sub2", "flag", "class", "sno", "status")
```

Error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`flag`' given input columns: [id, rollno, sub1, sub2];;
> 'Filter ('flag = C)

Expected result:

```
+---+------+----+----+----+-----+------+---+
| id|rollno|sub1|sub2|flag|class|status|sno|
+---+------+----+----+----+-----+------+---+
|  1|   111| 200| 200|   C|  5th|     Y| 11|
|  2|   222| 400| 400|   C|  5th|     Y| 22|
+---+------+----+----+----+-----+------+---+
```

Comment: Apply filter before grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After aggregation the other columns have disappeared, so you can't filter based on those. You need to filter before group by. Also you need to group by the other columns if you want to keep them.

```
var df2 = someDF
   .filter(col("flag") === "C")
   .filter(length(col("rollno")) >= 2)
   .filter(col("class") === ("5th") || col("class") === ("6th"))
   .filter(substring(col("rollno"), 1, 2) === col("sno"))
   .filter(col("status") === "Y")
   .groupBy("id", "rollno", "flag", "class", "sno", "status")
   .agg(sum("sub1").alias("sub1"),sum("sub2").alias("sub2"))
   .select("id", "rollno", "sub1", "sub2", "flag", "class", "sno", "status")

df2.show
+---+------+----+----+----+-----+---+------+
| id|rollno|sub1|sub2|flag|class|sno|status|
+---+------+----+----+----+-----+---+------+
|  1|   111| 200| 200|   C|  5th| 11|     Y|
|  2|   222| 400| 400|   C|  5th| 22|     Y|
+---+------+----+----+----+-----+---+------+
```